# Screenshots not found in HTML Publisher report after Jenkins build

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, jenkins-groovy

In my index.html file the embedded screenshots are not displayed when using Jenkins with HTML Publisher plugin. The screenshots are shown only when running my tests locally.

In the index.html file shown in the HTML Publisher plugin when I click on one of the embedded empty screenshots I'm getting:

HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_test/target/surefire-reports/Wed_Jan_23_14_33_19_UTC_2019.png. Reason:

Not Found

I have verified the screenshots get generated every time in this exact path. This is my code to set the screenshot location:

```
public void takeScreenshotMyOwn() {
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        String reportDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath() + "/target/surefire-reports/";
        File destFile = new File( reportDirectory + screenshotFileName());
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
        Reporter.log( htmlNewLine + htmlNewLine + "<a href='" + reportDirectory + destFile.getName() + "'> <img src='" + reportDirectory + destFile.getName() + "' height='200' width='340'/> </a>"+htmlNewLine);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Reporter.log("Failed to create screenshot");
        Reporter.log(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have searched all over and haven't found a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a more elegant answer but with the help of a developer I was able to create an external folder on our Apache server to store the images and link to them. Then I added parameters to our Jenkins server to alter the security policy and restarted. The screenshots are now showing up.

Comment: what parameters did you add to Jenkins ?